# Disable positive button in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've looked trough most of the posts here on stackoverflow, but I can't get this working. I want the positive button(register) to be disabled unless all fields are completed.

How can I achieve this?

```
public static class UsernameDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();


        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.ipcamaccount, null))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.action_register, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                       //some other code
                        }
                    }
                });

        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.ipcamaccount, null))
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.action_cancel, null);


        return builder.create();
    }
   }
```

Comment: Create your Custom Dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a different approach to get this done. Hope it saves someone the trouble. I'm using this in a RecyclerView Adapter, so you have to set context. I don't know if it's the most elegant way to do it, but it's working just fine.

Here is the code:

```
private void myDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    dialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.ipcamaccount);

    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.action_register, null);
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.action_cancel, null);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    Button positiveButton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onPositiveButtonClicked(alertDialog);
        }
    });

    Button negativeButton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);

    negativeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onNegativeButtonClicked(alertDialog);
        }
    });
}

private void onPositiveButtonClicked(AlertDialog alertDialog) {

      if(some condition) {

       alertDialog.dismiss();

        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Some toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Some other toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

private void onNegativeButtonClicked(AlertDialog alertDialog) {
    alertDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the positive button listener, validate the data, if the data is valid, proceed further, if not show a toast about the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Button positiveButton;
     @Override public void onStart() { 
     super.onStart();
     AlertDialog d = (AlertDialog) getDialog();
     if (d != null) {
     positiveButton = (Button)d.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
     positiveButton.setEnabled(false); 
     }
     }
```